# Why doesn't my login script function correctly after the user inputs the correct login details?

Tags: php, html

when the user enters the username and password for the script why doesn't it forward them onto the protected php page? Can someone help me fix my script please?

I have checked the file names and they're correct so I'm not really sure what to do next, I can't see the problem. Therefore, I thought I'd write a post about it on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

**login.php script**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $validated = false;

    session_start();
    if($user!=""&&$pass!="")
    {
        if($user=="test1"&&$pass=="test1")
            $validated = true;
        if($validated)
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = "OK";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;

            header('Location: protected.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = "";
            echo "Invalid username or password.";
        }
    }
    else $_SESSION['login'] = "";
}
?>

    <html>
     <body>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <p>Please enter your username and password:</p>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Username: </td>
                <td><input size=\"20\" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" name="username"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password: </td>
                <td><input size=\"20\" type="password" size="20" maxlength="15" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**protected script**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['login'] != "OK")
   {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
   }
?>
<html>
   <head
   <title>Protected Web Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Protected Web Page</h1>
      <<p>You have successfully logged in!</p>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
<p>
    Your username is: <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?=><br/>
    Your password is: <?= $_SESSION['password'] ?>
</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? You should `exit` after your `header` calls. Your `if($validated)` is not needed, if you are in that conditional already they are validated.

Comment: I don't have that enabled, I'll look into the now and thanks for the help. I'll try have a look into that now. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors and pointless code (explained in comments) - This will work:
(remove text after //)

**protected.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['login'] != "OK"){
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
   }
?>
<html>
   <head> // Missing closing bracket > 
   <title>Protected Web Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Protected Web Page</h1>
      <p>You have successfully logged in!</p> // had extra < at begining of line 
    <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
    <p>
        Your username is: <?php $_SESSION['username'] ?><br/> // dont use PHP opening and closing shortcodes, incorrect close
        Your password is: <?php $_SESSION['password'] ?> // dont use PHP opening and closing shortcodes
    </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // start session at top


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {  
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];

    if($user != "" || $pass != ""){ // should use || for OR, not AND 
        if($user=="test1"&&$pass=="test1"){ // this wilkl only work with this combination
        // removed validation boolean it's not needed
            $_SESSION['login'] = "OK";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;

            header('Location: protected.php');

        }else{
            $_SESSION['login'] = "";
            echo "Invalid username or password.";
        }
    }else{
      $_SESSION['login'] = "";  
      echo "Username or password cannot be blank"; // added echo for blank inputs
    } 
}
?>

    <html>
     <body>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <p>Please enter your username and password:</p>
        <form method="post">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Username: </td>
                <td><input size="20" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" name="username"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password: </td>
                <td><input size="20" type="password" size="20" maxlength="15" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```